# How to make neo4j docker image as read-only in the container?

Tags: docker, security, neo4j

I'm trying to enhance the security on neo4j under docker.

neo4j: 3.4.10 / 3.4.18
docker: 1.13.1

the docker command I used is listed as below

```
NEO4J_HOME=/var/lib/neo4j
docker run \
    -d \
    --name=neo4j \
    -v $NEO4J_HOME/logs:/logs \
    -v $NEO4J_HOME/data:/data \
    -v /tmp:/tmp \
    --publish=192.168.0.4:7474:7474 --publish=192.168.0.4:7687:7687 \
    --read-only \
    neo4j:3.4.18
```

However, the container cannot start and error is shown as below

```
[root@xxxxxx ~]# docker logs --tail all neo4j
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/neo4j': Read-only file system
```

I know that to implement the read-only flag, I will make the container root system read-only and I have to use the volume flag (-v) to let the neo4j can write data outside the containers. Just don't know what I missed...and no idea why the error message (changing ownership) here.

Comment: why don't you use dockerfile

Comment: or you want to do this in docker run command only ?

Comment: @DupinderSingh Sorry to very late reply. And I finally know the solution. But first, let me answer your question. I need to make the container as read-only container using --read-only.
The reason why I can't start the container with --read-only is that there is still some process in the container, writing file inside the container. The solution is easy and clear, it is to mount all possible container path to host path. For this case, there is one thing which is make sure the host file permission that container can write. (Check the process owner id)

Comment: if you found the answer then please add your solution as Answer. So that next visited will get the help